# Not allow duplicates in different HTML selects with the same content with javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have different selects with the same content and i want control that the user don't put the same value in two or more selects, i make this code, but i think there are some options better than this, I put here the code for share and at the same time ask if exist some better options. because i search some solution like this and i can't found.

```js
$(function () {
    function restrict_multiple(selector) {
        // Here sets the current value in your alt
        $(selector).each(function () {
            $(this).attr("alt", $(this).val());
        })
        // trigger when the select change
        $(selector).change(function () {
            // Remove the hidden from the <option>
            $(selector + " option").removeClass("hidden");
            
            // I use thr alt attr, like an aid to maintain the actual selected value
            $(this).attr("alt", $(this).val())
            
            // Create an array with the selected options
            var selected = new Array();
            
            // Every selected option is assigned into this array
            $(selector + " option:selected").each(function () {
                selected.push(this.value);
            })
                       
            // Apply the hidden the other select options
            for (k in selected) {
                if( selected[k] != "" ){
                    $(selector + "[alt!=" + selected[k] + "] option[value=" + selected[k] + "]").addClass("hidden")
                }
            }
            
        })
        
        // trigger to keep updated all selects 
        $(selector).each(function () { $(this).trigger("change"); })
    }
    
    //calling the function again sending the class
    restrict_multiple(".excluyent-select");
})
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="participantes_1" id="participantes_1" class="excluyent-select" >
    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    <option value="1">111111111111111111</option>
    <option value="2">222222222222222222</option>
    <option value="3">333333333333333333</option>
    <option value="4">444444444444444444</option>
    <option value="5">555555555555555555</option>
    <option value="6">666666666666666666</option>
    <option value="7">777777777777777777</option>
    <option value="8">888888888888888888</option>
    <option value="9">999999999999999999</option>
</select><br />
<select name="participantes_2" id="participantes_2" class="excluyent-select" >
    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    <option value="1">111111111111111111</option>
    <option value="2">222222222222222222</option>
    <option value="3">333333333333333333</option>
    <option value="4">444444444444444444</option>
    <option value="5">555555555555555555</option>
    <option value="6">666666666666666666</option>
    <option value="7">777777777777777777</option>
    <option value="8">888888888888888888</option>
    <option value="9">999999999999999999</option>
</select><br />
```

Here i put the link to some example running: http://jsfiddle.net/hevercking/xdmd87se/

Comment: It would help if the code comments were in the default Stack Overflow language (i.e. English) :)

Comment: Whoops, sorry TrueBlueAussie i didn't notice, I put it directly

Comment: comments in english :) sorry for this bloomer

Comment: Is this an attempt to get visitor to a link within your jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the js code to do it this way:

```
$(function () {

    function restrict_multiple(selector) {

       $(selector).each(function () {$(this).attr("alt", $(this).val());});

       $(selector).on('change', function () {

           var ind = $(this).index();
           var val = $(this).val();
           var alt = $(this).attr('alt');

           $(selector).each(function () {

               $(this).find("option[value="+alt+"]").removeClass("hidden");

               if($(this).index() != ind && val != "") {
                   $(this).find("option[value="+val+"]").addClass("hidden");
               }

           });

           $(this).attr('alt', val);

       });

    }

    restrict_multiple(".excluyent-select");

})
```

Let me know if it works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/48zmLm7x/5/

Answer (score 0):

Great! i like more your option, but the two options i discover have one problem and i don't know how to solve, if i generate the selects with one for.

```js
for ( var i=0; i < 2; i++ ) {
    $('<p><select name="grup_'+i+'" id="grup_'+i+'" class="excluyent-select")"><option value="">Seleccionar</option><option value="1">111111111111111111</option><option value="2">222222222222222222</option><option value="3">333333333333333333</option><option value="4">444444444444444444</option><option value="5">555555555555555555</option><option value="6">666666666666666666</option><option value="7">777777777777777777</option><option value="8">888888888888888888</option><option value="9">999999999999999999</option></select></p>').appendTo('#selecs');
}

$(function () {
    
    function restrict_multiple(selector) {
       
       $(selector).each(function () {$(this).attr("alt", $(this).val());});
        
       $(selector).on('change', function () {
           
           var ind = $(this).index();
           var val = $(this).val();
           var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
           
           $(selector).each(function () {
               
               $(this).find("option[value="+alt+"]").removeClass("hidden");
               
               if($(this).index() != ind && val != "") {
                   $(this).find("option[value="+val+"]").addClass("hidden");
               }
               
           });
           
           $(this).attr('alt', val);
           
       });
       
    }
    
    restrict_multiple(".excluyent-select");
    
})
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selecs">
    
</div>
```

in this case don't run http://jsfiddle.net/hevercking/t3qg45v3/

I try make with onChange but only start to remove when i change one select the second time and if i change don't apear again until remove all options in the other select, i put here the example: http://jsfiddle.net/hevercking/e4scbtre/3/

Comment: In your second fiddle, you are calling the function from the html onchange="restrict_multiple('.excluyent-select')". It won't work that way because the restrict_multiple is declaring an onchange event: $(selector).on('change', function () ...

Comment: To get the first fiddle working, use a delegate function because the created elements are not yet in the dom when the function is parsed (the browser always render functions first)